# How to extend a SQL statement to incorporate multiple criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL statement here

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ACB
FROM APPL
WHERE CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%(' AND APPL.CRE_TS >= to_date('20190801','yyyymmdd') 
    AND APPL.CRE_TS <  to_date('20190802','yyyymmdd')
```

Now this finds all the applications in a database that end with a '(' symbol on the proper date.  Is it possible to extend this singular query so it works with other applications in my database that end in A or B or C or whatever? They all need to fall on that same date. I just need to count each application type and put it in a column that has a name of my choosing.

Should I be using 'OR' in the where section?

Comment: Note that this doesn't look for any row that has applications that ends with a "(", it simply must contain a "(" anywhere in the CPTR_APPL_ID .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways (actually many ways but these are relatively easy to understand

#### Select counts:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT CPTR_APPL_ID as typ
  FROM APPL
  WHERE APPL.CRE_TS >= DATE '2019-08-01' AND 
  APPL.CRE_TS < DATE '2019-08-02'
)
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte WHERE typ LIKE '%A') as count_a,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte WHERE typ LIKE '%B') as count_b,
  ...
FROM dual
```

I've never been a fan of "select in select list" queries. This one has the potential to be quite poor performing depending on how many times oracle needs to scan the table to do the counting. You'd hope the cte will be processed as a first step, which is a reduced result set that would then be counted, but your optimiser might plan things very differently

#### Plain ISO SQL pivot method:

```
  SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%A' THEN 1 END) as COUNT_A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CPTR_APPL_ID LIKE '%B' THEN 1 END) as COUNT_B,
    ...
  FROM APPL
  WHERE APPL.CRE_TS >= DATE '2019-08-01' AND 
  APPL.CRE_TS < DATE '2019-08-02'
```

My preferred method of pivoting as it works on all DB. Basically the case when turn your data into either null or 1 depending if it ends in A or not (or B etc) then SUM sums all the 1 giving a count. Sum ignores nulls. Can be extended by having columns that are not summed, as long as those columns appear in a group by. Performance should be good because it can be done in a single pass over the data returned from the WHERE filter

#### Pivot syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT SUBSTR(CPTR_APPL_ID, -1) as typ
  FROM APPL
  WHERE APPL.CRE_TS >= DATE '2019-08-01' AND 
  APPL.CRE_TS < DATE '2019-08-02'
)
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT(typ)
  FOR typ
  IN ('A', 'B', ...) --this could be a query if you wanted dynamic
)
```

Downside is it's proprietary, but it can be dynamic or fixed column values. Some people really dig this and remember the syntax, other people (me) always have to look it up

Let me know if any of these queries have typos - they've been written without any testing. They all need some adjustment for the specific codes your want, hopefully you can see the pattern in all of them and extend it

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks like Oracle to me.  I think an aggregation query does what you want:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CPTR_APPL_ID, -1), COUNT(*) AS ACB
FROM APPL
WHERE APPL.CRE_TS >= DATE '2019-08-01' AND 
      APPL.CRE_TS < DATE '2019-08-02'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(CPTR_APPL_ID, -1);
```

Comment: The only bit I ponder about is where he says he needs to count the app type and put it in a column named as he chooses, which sounds like a pivot query..

Comment: The -1 in substr returns the final char at the end of the string (it substr beginning with string index of str_length - 1 ie the last char). If you're familiar with other databases , bb etc it's th equivalent of RIGHT(str, 1)

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes you're right altho this query produces the right result I still need to name each column a specific something is there a way to do that with this query or no?

Comment: You can alias any column using AS. When you say "each column" how many columns are you expecting? (Do you want a result set that is two columns 26 rows, one column for the 26 rows one row per char,  the other column for the count, or do you want 26 columns one for each char and one row of all the counts?)

Comment: @CaiusJard there a total of 8 columns all of them end in a specific character.

Comment: I think we could do with seeing some example data and a required output

Comment: @CaiusJard So there are 8 types of apps in the database that have a bunch of numbers and end in a certain character like B or C or Q and I just need to count how many end in Q and call it like Q_Count and how many end in a C and call that column C_Count etc, is data required for this?

Comment: @stackflow added an answer that gives the columnar format you're after